# Scrape 'strong' class Scrapy

Tags: python, html, css, scrapy

I am trying to scrape where it says 'Piza, Italian' from this DOM:

[image]

I have attempted using:

```
restaurants = response.css('.restaurant-content')

for restaurant in restaurants:
    name = restaurant.css('.serpItemList-Title::text').extract()
    cuisine = restaurant.css('infoText.infoText--primary.listing-item--cuisineText::text').extract()
```

The name of each restaurant is being retrieved without any issues however the Cuisine simply is not being retrieved/populated.

How can I retrieve the cuisine?

*Note* I would like to achieve this WITHOUT xpath as I need to loop through every cuisine in every restaurant and xpath does not support this, it just takes one specific location in the DOM.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's kind of hard for me to be able to say what would work without seeing the whole thing.  Maybe `.div` ? Try using Chrome extension selector gadget.  It will help 1000%

Comment: You're missing a dot (.) - probably just `.infoText` will do